# Optimizing Disk I/O when running Redis and PostgreSQL on a single machine

Tags: redis

**Background:**

I have a live Django app that utilizes 4 Redis instances.

The first two are big in size: back ups amount to ~2GB and ~4.4GB respectively. The other two are small: ~85M and ~15M.

`redis-server --version` yields `Redis server v=4.0.2 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-4.0.3 bits=64 build=401ce53d7b0383ca`.

---

**The problem:**

It's a busy server running PostgreSQL 9.6.5 as well. PG data and Redis backups are both saved in the secondary drive `xvdb`.

I've noticed that whenever my big Redis instances start backing up, disk I/O naturally spikes and PostgreSQL commit statements start piling up in the slow log. Behold:

```
21:49:26.171 UTC [44861] ubuntu@myapp LOG:  duration: 3063.262 ms  statement: COMMIT
21:49:26.171 UTC [44890] ubuntu@myapp LOG:  duration: 748.307 ms  statement: COMMIT
21:49:26.171 UTC [44882] ubuntu@myapp LOG:  duration: 1497.461 ms  statement: COMMIT
21:49:26.171 UTC [44893] ubuntu@myapp LOG:  duration: 655.063 ms  statement: COMMIT
21:49:26.171 UTC [44894] ubuntu@myapp LOG:  duration: 559.743 ms  statement: COMMIT
21:49:26.172 UTC [44883] ubuntu@myapp LOG:  duration: 1415.733 ms  statement: COMMIT
```

As a consequence, this is how my PostgreSQL commits look like every day:

[image]

---

**The question:**

Is there anything I can do on the Redis side to help smoothe out this spikey situation? I'd like Redis and PostgreSQL to live in as much harmony as they possibly can on a single machine.

---

**More information:**

Ask for more information if you need it.

Machine specs:

```
AWS EC2 m4.4xlarge (16 cores, 64GB RAM)
Elastic Block Store gp2 volumes (105 IOPS, burst upto 3000 IOPS)
```

The following config exists in the `Append Only Mode` section of my Redis conf files:

```
appendonly no
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
# appendfsync always
appendfsync everysec
# appendfsync no
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
aof-load-truncated yes
aof-use-rdb-preamble no
```

Typical `iostat -xmt 3` values are:

```
10/15/2017 08:28:35 PM
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          10.44    0.00    0.93    0.15    0.06   88.43

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.00     0.00    0.00    2.00     0.00     0.04    38.67     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
xvdb              0.00     2.67    0.00   44.67     0.00     0.41    18.99     0.13    2.81    0.00    2.81   1.07   4.80
```

Compare that to the same around the time slow commits are logged:

```
10/15/2017 10:18:11 PM

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           8.16    0.00    0.65   11.90    0.04   79.24

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.00     4.00    0.00    1.00     0.00     0.02    48.00     0.00    1.33    0.00    1.33   1.33   0.13
xvdb              0.00     0.00    1.67 1312.00     0.01   163.50   254.90   142.56  107.64   25.60  107.75   0.76 100.00
```

The first Redis instance has the following snapshotting config:

```
save 7200 1
#save 300 10
#save 60 10000
```

The second Redis instance has the following snapshotting config:

```
save 21600 10
#save 300 10
#save 60 10000
```

Answer (score -1):

I can suggest one solution - `docker`. `docker` has the capability to limit the os resources that a particular container will use. In your case, the os resource seems to be the disk i/o.

> The --device-read-bps flag limits the read rate (bytes per second)
>   from a device. For example, this command creates a container and
>   limits the read rate to 1mb per second from /dev/sda:
>
> $ docker run -it --device-read-bps /dev/sda:1mb

docker also has a flag `--device-read-iops=[]` which limit read rate (IO per second) from a device.

Your image here will be `redis`, but it won't hurt to move `postgres` also to `docker`. This will help you limit the disk i/o rates on redis containers so that postgres has more of it.

This solution should work for you but the infrastructure changes might be a little painful to achieve.

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36145817/how-to-limit-io-speed-in-docker-and-share-file-with-system-in-the-same-time) SO post for `docker` limit `i/o` speed

Comment: This is my only realistic choice given the scenario?

Comment: you can wait for other answers... meanwhile I will try to figure out if it is possible at os level.

Comment: @HassanBaig did you go through this link? `https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48138/how-to-throttle-per-process-i-o-to-a-max-limit`

Comment: That my friend is a useful link as well. Thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: if u found it helpful do upvote, accept the solution.

Comment: Yep, I'm going to try your docker solution in a while, probably will accept if everything goes A-OK by the morning. Native I/O throttling and/or using a separate host are also options that are on the table. I'll get back to this.