# Does it make sense to run a command with ionice in docker container with a bind mount

Tags: docker, ionice

Let's say I'm archiving files from a bind mount in a docker container and want to set a priority for disk time, so I run it like:

```
ionice -c2 -n7 tar....
```

Would that work? Would the host OS consider the class/priority that comes from a container (cgroups)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tests showed that `ionice` did not have any significant effect on `tar` performance, instead, I use RAM/CPU docker container limits

Answer (score 0):

That should make sense:

- if this tar command is not bottlenecked on CPU for gzip or similar
- if your system is running with the CFQ IO scheduler for the disk(s) that you are using, according to the notes section of: [man ionice](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice)

To check your systems configuration try:

```
for SCHEDULER in /sys/block/*/queue/scheduler; do echo "For disk: ${SCHEDULER}"; cat $SCHEDULER; done
```

To get an overview of disks and file-systems use:

```
lsblk
```

For other possible solutions with Docker v 1.10 features see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36145817/how-to-limit-io-speed-in-docker-and-share-file-with-system-in-the-same-time#36624678)